How to solve error invalid request BLR at offset 68 input parameter mismatch for procedure ZP_CHECK_FORMAT_INSERT
I have the following error in the Firebird Database. version 2.5.2
invalid request BLR at offset 68
input parameter mismatch for procedure ZP_CHECK_FORMAT_INSERT

How can I debug this problem? Anyone can help me to sort out this problem.
enter image description here
An error occurs when restoring the database

Please don't post screenshots of code, post them as code formatted text. In addition, provide the exact steps to reproduce the error. The error suggests the compiled form (BLR) of something calling your stored procedure is broken. You will need to fix that in the source database and back it up again. That said, barring a clear reproduction recipe, it might be better to ask on firebird-support, as Stack Overflow is not really suitable for debugging these kinds of issues.

Problem is not with backup but original database and it cannot be solved for backup. Just drop the procedure and all dependent objects. Then recreate them from master-script. Then make a new backup that should be restored ok.
